# Masturbating in Ramadan

Tags: sin, sawm, ramadan, tawba, masturbation

I wanted to ask if God will forgive me for masturbating in Ramadan, I am a teen and I am unfortunately addicted to masturbation, so I promised myself that This Ramadan I won't masturbate which was the case for the majority of this holy month but I started feeling really uncomfortable when I'm having a boner to the point where i cannot focus on anything and i have unfortunately masturbated 3 times this month and was asking if God would forgive me if i started praying more, I Feel like i cannot stop completely and i don't know what to do, I Felt huge guilt the first time, then did it a second time a couple days later and felt a lot of guilt and today i also did it and I am feeling guilt and feeling like i have to ask if i could be forgiven or if I have to do something specific during this month to repent.

Comment: Allah will not punish you for that if you really can't control and tried your best. Also watch [this](https://youtu.be/sDFxGu47Zu0)

Comment: @Yusha The video talks about masturbation but not in Ramadan. While I agree with Zakir Naik on the ruling on masturbation, he himself said [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=45WYZqRquMs) regarding masturbation in Ramadan.

Answer (score 1):

If you masturbated while fasting, note that you will have to make up your fasts. Ejaculation & sexual intimacy breaks your fast.

As for sinning and needing repentance: 
**Yes. Allah will forgive you.** It doesn’t matter how big of a sin is, repent. Don’t underestimate the mercy of Allah. It’s so grand that if you were to deliberately sin, disobey Him, he still gives you the luxuries you need to live. There is not a single thing He will not forgive. But you have to make that choice to repent from that haram deed regardless of the number of times you sin.

Answer (score 0):

Allah (SWT) will never turn  away a muslim if he comes to him to repent and comes to him with pure intentions. if you mean to repent from your heart without any games or thinking you can deceive Allah then your repentance WILL be accepted. after all he is “the most merciful” and “the all knowing”. as far as masturbating during ramadan if it is done during fasting then you must make up for that day of fasting and like i said you MUST repent for that pretty serious sin and beg Allah (SWT) to give you the strength to not fall into that trap again. don’t ever doubt Allahs mercy as that is when you won’t get any.